# Is there a better way to create this game loop? (C++/Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, global-variables

I'm working on a Windows game, and I have this:

```
bool game_cont;

LRESULT WINAPI WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_QUIT: case WM_CLOSE: case WM_DESTROY: game_cont = false; break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(/*lots of parameters*/)
{
    //tedious initialization

    //game loop
    while(game_cont)
    {
        //give message to WinProc
        if(!GameRun()) game_cont = false;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and I am wondering if there is a better way to do this (ignoring timers &c. for right now) than to have `game_cont` be global.  In short, I need to be able to exit the while in `WinMain` from `WinProc`, so that if the user presses the closes out of the game in a way other that the game's in game menu, the program wont keep running in memory.  (As it did when I tested this without the `game_cont..` statement in `WinProc`.

Oh, and on a side note, `GameRun` is basically a bool that returns false when the game ends, and true otherwise.

Comment: You should only exit when receiving `WM_QUIT`, and handle `WM_DESTROY` by calling `PostQuitMessage`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, use [PeekMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644943(VS.85).aspx), it's the standard in game development.

This is the best approach, I believe:

```
int Run()
{
    MSG msg;
    while(true)
    {
        if(::PeekMessage(&msg,0,0,0 PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if(msg.message == WM_QUIT || 
                       msg.message == WM_CLOSE || 
                       msg.message == WM_DESTROY)
                break;

            ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
            ::DispatchMessage(&msg);           
        }
        else
        {
            //Run game code
                    if(!GameRun())
                         break;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680921/better-game-loops-then-endless-loop-block) (specially the first answer)

Comment: I would probably pass a 'game ending' value through to the GameRun code to allow it to clean up when you choose to exit the app, rather than just using 'break'. But the general structure is exactly right.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, I think that would be better.

Comment: PeekMessage is the right approach to doing background work when no messages are present, but `WM_CLOSE` and `WM_DESTROY` should not be handled in the main message loop.  Right now you're going to abort the entire program whenever any child control or invisible message helper window is destroyed!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [*exit*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/exit/).
Use [*atexit*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atexit/) to make sure that WM_CLOSE gets to the message que when its time to exit.

I don't know what's the ultimate design here, but it's an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could make `game_cont` `static` to your main file which has `WinMain`/`WinProc`, but I don't know of a significantly better structure.

Answer (score 0):

No, don't do that.

`WM_QUIT` *is* your flag.  `GetMessage` return value indicates when `WM_QUIT` is encountered.

Your main window will never receive `WM_QUIT`, as it isn't sent to a window.  `WM_CLOSE` will call `DestroyWindow` by default, so you don't need any special handling for that.  Handle `WM_DESTROY` by calling `PostQuitMessage`, which results in `WM_QUIT` on your thread, the special return value from `GetMessage`, and stops your message dispatch loop.