# Penalties of a script constantly looping in the background

Tags: python, resources, performance, queue

I know this topic has been [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680921#681336) in the [past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379231), but I am a tiny bit paranoid about resource usage.

I am looking into writing a daemon for queing jobs to archive files into zip files for a web app i am working on. It would behave something like this:

```
while True:
    while morejobs():
        zipfile()
    sleep(15seconds)
```

What sort of resources would be consumed by a process constantly looping away in the background (provided there is nothing to zip)? Is there anything i should be aware of or careful of?

### Edit:

It looks like most of the answers are concerned about the duration of the sleep.  I blindly set it to sleep (in the code example) for 15 milliseconds at a time. I actually intended it to be 15 seconds, and i have 'updated' the code to reflect that.

### Edit Again:

What would be the lowest reasonable  time for the script to be sleeping? Is 5 seconds to low? I have no idea what the load of this app would be or how often new jobs would be added to the queue.

Comment: Actually, your original code was correct.  time.sleep() takes seconds (milliseconds are indicated by passing a floating point arg, eg 0.001)

Answer (score 4):

Sleep involves no overhead.  The Linux OS uses a very simple signal to wake a sleeping process.

What you're showing is the "busy-waiting" design pattern.

To eliminate overhead, you want to be woken ONLY when there's work to do.

Ways to do this.

1. Wait on read.
2. Wait on a select function call.  See http://docs.python.org/library/select.html
3. Wait for a lock to be released.  See http://docs.python.org/library/posixfile.html.

Of these, waiting on a read is perhaps easiest.  Reading from a pipe or a socket is what you want to do.

I'm guessing that you have a "multiple-writers-single-reader" design pattern.  In this case, there are two candidate solutions.

1. Multiple requests per socket.  This is the FTP-like solution where you write a simple server that listens for connections on one socket and opens a dedicated connection for each client.  Then you use select to determine which client is sending a file.
2. Single request per socket.  This is the HTTP-like solution where you receive requests in some socket and the request is a big flood of data.  When the request is all finished, the socket is closed so another client can get it.

In these two cases, you're not sleeping --  you're waiting for I/O's to complete.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sleeping for 15 seconds, it might be better to have a callback which restarts your job when new files arrive.

- Process available files
- Check for new files every 60 seconds or whatever interval you choose
- When a new file arrives, process it and any others which may have arrived since the last interval

Comment: sleep(15) sleeps for 15 seconds, not 15 milliseconds. http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.sleep

Comment: @S.Lott Thanks for the clarification, in my primarily .NET world Sleep() is specified in MS.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a cron job to run a script every minute or so? At least you are not depending on your own loop to be continuously running in the background.

Comment: A cron job gives a lot more CPU load as a loop sleeping the same duration, since the program has to be loaded into memory and a new process is created for every iteration. With the loop it just runs one more cycle, then goes back to sleep.

Comment: I think the overhead is worth the standard tried and true simplicity of cron to a custom script running contantly on my machine. To each their own I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If it takes (and these figures are examples) 20 seconds for a file to arrive and 5 seconds for you to process it, what is the harm in your process waiting for, on average, another 7.5 seconds before it even detects that the file is there?

A sleeping process should have as close to zero impact on the CPU as it is possible to get.

So no, I would not be concerned about this aspect at all.

The one thing you should be concerned about is how to restart the process automatically if it fails. I would run a cron job every 5 minutes (your choice of actual frequency) to kill off the old copy (politely, and only if it's running) and then start a new one. That way, there'll only be a 5-minute downtime at most if something goes wrong.

I say politely because the old one may be in the middle of processing files and you should not interrupt that unless it's recoverable.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can lower the priority of your process.
(I'm only familiar with the windows method)

On Windows:

```
def setpriority(pid=None,priority=1):
    """ Set The Priority of a Windows Process.  Priority is a value between 0-5 where
        2 is normal priority.  Default sets the priority of the current
        python process but can take any valid process ID. """

    import win32api,win32process,win32con

    priorityclasses = [win32process.IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                       win32process.BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                       win32process.NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                       win32process.ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                       win32process.HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                       win32process.REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS]
    if pid == None:
        pid = win32api.GetCurrentProcessId()
    handle = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, True, pid)
    win32process.SetPriorityClass(handle, priorityclasses[priority])
```

from:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496767/

Answer (score 0):

This has the potential to hammer your CPU, even when there is nothing to process.

**Edit:** Actually [`sleep()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.sleep) takes an argument as a number of seconds, not milliseconds so I don't think the CPU is going to be a problem.  Still, perhaps you could use a cron job to schedule something like this.

Comment: This is supposed to be redistributable, and be able to be set up with the minimal amount of fuss. I think i am already adding a bit to much 'complexity' without having cron jobs all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the cost of hammering your cpu, there is the cost of the *morejobs()* call. You can mitigate by using a higher value for *sleep()*, or you can use some sort of mailbox that receives requests and then fires the *zipfile()* operation.

It is normal for some operations to have a background thread scheduled that temporarily checks for something. In this case the best is to use sensible values for *sleep()*.

Answer (score 0):

"A thousand reasoned opinions are worth one measurement".

Just try it.